# Getting a list of all dependencies in the Versions Catalogue from Gradle v7+

Tags: gradle, gradle-dependencies

Gradle 7 introduced a [versions catalogue](https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.1/release-notes.html#centralized-versions). With it I can easily refer to a dependency as e.g. `libs.jacksonCore` if it is defined in `gradle/libs.versions.toml`:

```
[versions]
jackson = "2.11.1"

[libraries]
jacksonCore = { module = "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core", version.ref = "jackson" }
```

But is there a way to programmatically get a list of all the defined dependencies?

Right now I use reflection on the `libs` object (which is of class `org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForLibs`) as a workaround, but that's really ugly:

```
Map deps = libs.metaClass.methods
               .findAll { it.returnType.name.endsWith("provider.Provider") }
               .findAll { it.name.startsWith("get") }
               .collect { libs."$it.name"().get() }
               .collectEntries { [
                 (it.getModule().toString()): it.getVersionConstraint().toString()
               ] }
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the reflection hack in the OP since I couldn't get `findDependency()` to work on the already-defined `libs` in Gradle 7.3 (it worked in 7.2).  By fetching the `VersionCatalog` manually I managed to get rid of the hack:

```
def libz = rootProject.extensions
               .getByType(VersionCatalogsExtension).named("libs")
def deps = libz.getDependencyAliases()
               .collect { libz.findDependency(it).get().get() }
               .collectEntries {
                 [(it.getModule().toString()): it.getVersionConstraint().toString()]
               }
```

I'd still be interested in other improvements, though.

Comment: Seems like `getDependencyAliases` was renamed to `getLibraryAliases` and `findDependency` to `findLibrary` since Gradle 7.4